# Java ArrayList with comparable

Tags: java, arraylist

I have searched the internet and I cant find the answer to my question. I am coding my own arraylist structure. I wish to make it a sorted array that will receive a object from a contact class to be sorted by last name. i have this so far but I cant manage how to do the add() method.

```
public class SortedArrayList <E extends Comparable<E>> implements SortedList<E>  {
private int currentSize;

private E elements[];



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SortedArrayList(int initialCapacity){
    if(initialCapacity < 1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need at least one element");
    }

    this.currentSize = 0;
    this.elements = (E[]) new Object[initialCapacity];

}

@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new ListIterator<E>();
}

@Override
public boolean add(E obj) {


    if(obj == null){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("object cannot be null.");
    }

    if(this.currentSize == this.elements.length){
        reAllocate();
    }
    E temp[];
    temp = elements;
    for(int i=0; i<= this.currentSize; i++){

            //if(obj.compareTo(elements[i]) < 0){
                //int target =i;
                //elements[i+1] = temp[i];
                //elements[target] = obj;
                //break;

            }


    }
    this.elements[this.currentSize++] = obj;        




    return true;
}
```

Comment: I can suggest a better way if you tell me which class `E` represent and show me its structure.

Comment: Take a look at using `Arrays.binarySearch` to identify the exact index in elements[] where insertion should occur and then edit your array similar to what happens inside `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: E will be a last name (String) from a Class contacts.

Comment: @MarelisMolinaOtero can you please check, this will help you what you are exactly looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, you can do it by using Apache Commons [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) [BeanComparator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html#BeanComparator%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Take a look at this [example](http://www.shunmuga.com/?p=209)

Check this SO: [Comparator vs Apache BeanComparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441623/comparator-vs-apache-beancomparator?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

This is resamble like your E class based on which you want to do some sorting.

```
public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>{

private String fname;
private String lname;

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}
public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Customer o) {
    return this.lname.compareTo(o.lname);
}

}
```

And this is your SortedList class :

```
public class SortedList{

List<Customer> custList = null;
public SortedList() {
    custList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
}

public Iterator<Customer> iterator(){
    return custList.iterator();
}

public void add(Customer c){
    custList.add(c);
    Customer[] cust= (Customer[]) custList.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(cust);
    custList = Arrays.asList(cust);
}
}
```

Now whenever you invoke `add` method, it will add customer into currentList and sort as per last name.

Hope this helps you.